# Rails/Sidekiq/Devise: Is the job being handled by Sidekiq? How can I be sure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I've set Devise to send emails asynchronously, like so:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    DeviseMailerJob.perform_now(devise_mailer, notification, id, *args)
  end
end

class DeviseMailerJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :mailers

  def perform(devise_mailer, method, user_id, *args)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    devise_mailer.send(method, user, *args).deliver_now
  end
end
```

My `sidekiq.yml` looks like this:

```
---
:concurrency: 5
:queues:
  - mailers
```

I can go to the sign up page, sign up and I will see that everything seems ok in the logs:

```
2018-10-09T10:02:27.793848+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
[2018-10-09T10:02:27.793770 #4]  INFO -- :
[646a58f7-9588-4a1f-a258-9fbede3cf87d] [ActiveJob] [DeviseMailerJob]
[5ceac77e-d498-4436-8f12-7cd4aff2c004] Performed DeviseMailerJob (Job ID:
5ceac77e-d498-4436-8f12-7cd4aff2c004) from Sidekiq(mailers) in 3301.06ms
```

But the job does not show up in the Sidekiq dashboard. I do receive the confirmation email however. So the job *does* get processed. Only, I cannot be sure that Sidekiq is handling it.

Looking at the Heroku logs, I cannot see any logs from Sidekiq. On the dashboard, I would expect to see the 'processed' tally increment for every email that is sent. I'm not sure how to investigate this.

With Heroku, what's the best way of seeing wether or not the job is being handled by Sidekiq? Is there anything in my code to suggest that the job isn't being handled by Sidekiq?

Comment: Where is your Sidekiq worker ?

Comment: On Heroku. `=== worker (Free): bundle exec sidekiq (1)
worker.1: up 2018/10/09 10:50:21 +0100 (~ 19m ago)`

Comment: Nope, not your Heroku worker, but your Sidekiq worker. Sidekiq works with worker class objects. If you haven't coded any worker then probably your async job is not going through Sidekiq. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: Is that necessary if I'm using ActiveJob? `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq`

Comment: "perform_now" is not async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've explicitly told the code to execute immediately by calling perform_now:

```
DeviseMailerJob.perform_now
```